# TypeLoadExpection, cannot use types from libraries from my project

Tags: c#, types

I'm making some kind of game engine. I've got problem with TypeLoadExpection.
This is how my solution explorer looks:

http://screenshooter.net/data/uploads/rc/sg/cohk.jpg (I'm posting it as link because I don't have enough rep.)

If I use any of types from PolyEngine in PolyEngineRuntime, I'm getting TypeLoadExpection!
I have no idea why it's happening. I can post code if it helps to solve the problem, but I don't think the code will be useful.

Edit:
Here's code: http://pastebin.com/M508FhAC

Log is a static class from PolyEngine.

Here's how expection looks like:

Could not load type 'PolyEngine.Log' from assembly 'PolyEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: How are you loading the types, are you loading them correctly? Why 'load' the types at all, since you referenced the project/assembly, you should be able to just use them.

Comment: I think the code might actually be helpful just to clarify exactly how you're using them.

Comment: I'm not "loading" any types. I just referenced PolyEngine project and that's all. No idea what's going on.

Comment: Show some code, and how and when the exception is being thrown.

Comment: I have added code and how the expection is being thrown. The expection is being thrown before the application even starts, I THINK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably for some reason the PolyEngine DLL isn't automatically copied to the /bin folder of the PolyEngineRuntime. Or, if the PolyEngineRuntime uses types from yet another assembly, the external DLL is missing.

After build is complete, verify that all *.dlls are in the PolyEngineRuntime's /bin folder, from where you run your application.

Comment: Look at the expection I've just added. It cannot load type from PolyEngine assembly. And i'm sure that the PolyEngine dll is automatically copied to the folder where runtime exe is.

Comment: And what about the OpenTK.dll? Also, could you pastebin the PolyEngine.Log class?

Comment: OpenTK.dll works well. The expection is about PolyEngine.dll. Source of PolyEngine.Log: http://pastebin.com/AiqUURuu (Every class is not working, not only PolyEngine.Log)

Comment: If OpenTK.dll is missing from the directory, the PolyEngine.dll will not load since it uses OpenTK.dll. Can you double check the folder to contain PolyEngineRuntime.exe, PolyEngine.dll and OpenTK.dll? If you forgot to switch the reference to "Copy Always", the OpenTK.dll is not automatically copied to the output folder.

Comment: I double checked it, OpenTK.dll is not missing. You can check it yourself: http://pastebin.com/2BxwLNiy

Comment: Ok. The best you can do then is to inspect the InnerException of the exception and then InnerException's InnerException (and so on until it's null). It is possible that the real cause of the exception is somewhere in the inner exception chain.

Comment: InnerExpection is null in my TypeLoadExpection. This problem is really weird, nothing helps. Maybe i'm getting the expection because i was changing output paths in project configuration. I'll try to create new solution, and copy/paste source files, maybe it'll work.

Comment: What you can also do is to use the fuslogvw.exe tool and analyze binding logs. Chances are that a more detailed information can be found this way.

Comment: I solved this problem. I just created new solution and copied source files. It works now. Thanks for help.